# Converting factors consisting of multiple numbers to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

Converting factors to numeric has been dealt with multiple times, but my issue is when I have multiple numbers within the factor. For instance, here is a small subset of my data.frame:

```
                    AF      AC   AN   EAS_AF         AMR_AF
1          0.000199681       1 5008    0.001            0.0
2           0.00319489      16 5008      0.0            0.0
3 0.024361, 0.00479233 122, 24 5008 0.0, 0.0 0.0043, 0.0014
4           0.00439297      22 5008      0.0         0.0014
5          0.000798722       4 5008      0.0            0.0
```

Normally I would use the `as.numeric` and `levels` functions in combination to convert these factors into numbers. However, row three has two numbers in each entry, and therefore I get an NA when attempting this method on these variables. Is there any way to get round this? I have too many of these such cases to manually pluck them out.

My overall objective is to test whether each entry in each of these columns is greater than 0 (so if there are two numbers, I would test both), which is why I am attempting to convert into numeric in the first place. If there is any other smarter way around this problem I'd be willing to try it.

As requested, below is the `dput` of a reduced version of my data frame (taking only the first 10 rows).

```
structure(list(CHROM = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L), POS = c(180109L, 209892L, 221335L, 239445L, 246927L, 246928L, 
246933L, 246955L, 246970L), ID = structure(c(6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("rs143013573", "rs1431845", "rs145483680", 
"rs151111729", "rs547339499", "rs547699134", "rs556577288", "rs575589407", 
"rs72770983"), class = "factor"), REF = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G"), class = "factor"), 
    ALT = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "G", "G, T", "T"), class = "factor"), AF = structure(c(1L, 
    5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("0.000199681", 
    "0.000798722", "0.000998403", "0.00239617", "0.00319489", 
    "0.00439297", "0.024361, 0.00479233", "0.220248"), class = "factor"), 
    AC = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "1103", "12", "122, 24", "16", "22", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    AN = c(5008L, 5008L, 5008L, 5008L, 5008L, 5008L, 5008L, 5008L, 
    5008L), EAS_AF = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0", "0.0, 0.0", "0.001", "0.248"), class = "factor"), 
    AMR_AF = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0.0", 
    "0.0014", "0.0043, 0.0014", "0.1599"), class = "factor"), 
    AFR_AF = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0", 
    "0.003", "0.0121", "0.0159", "0.09, 0.0", "0.1611"), class = "factor"), 
    EUR_AF = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0", 
    "0.0, 0.0089", "0.0089", "0.2495"), class = "factor"), SAS_AF = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0", "0.0, 0.0143", 
    "0.001", "0.0051", "0.2843"), class = "factor"), consequence = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("stop_gained", 
    "synonymous_variant"), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ZMYND11", class = "factor"), 
    accession = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "NM_006624.5", class = "factor"), gene_type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "protein_coding", class = "factor")), .Names = c("CHROM", 
"POS", "ID", "REF", "ALT", "AF", "AC", "AN", "EAS_AF", "AMR_AF", 
"AFR_AF", "EUR_AF", "SAS_AF", "consequence", "gene", "accession", 
"gene_type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Can you add the `dput`? The class of the columns matter.

Comment: Hi, what exactly is dput? I looked up the function but am unfamiliar with it's usage. What are you specifically asking me to add?

Comment: type `dput(df)` (with your df of course) and add the result in the question. This gives us the structure of your table.

Comment: The output is incredibly large as my df contains 17 columns and 408045 rows.

Comment: try to make a small table like the one in your question.

Comment: I have added this, using only the first ten rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(ALT,AF,AC,EAS_AF,AMR_AF,AFR_AF,EUR_AF,SAS_AF, convert=TRUE)

   CHROM    POS          ID REF   AN        consequence    gene   accession      gene_type ALT          AF   AC EAS_AF AMR_AF AFR_AF
1     10 180109 rs547699134   G 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   A 0.000199681    1  0.001 0.0000 0.0000
2     10 209892 rs151111729   C 5008        stop_gained ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   G 0.003194890   16  0.000 0.0000 0.0121
3     10 221335 rs143013573   C 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   G 0.024361000  122  0.000 0.0043 0.0900
4     10 221335 rs143013573   C 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   T 0.004792330   24  0.000 0.0014 0.0000
5     10 239445 rs145483680   G 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   A 0.004392970   22  0.000 0.0014 0.0159
6     10 246927 rs547339499   A 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   G 0.000798722    4  0.000 0.0000 0.0030
7     10 246928  rs72770983   A 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   G 0.002396170   12  0.001 0.0014 0.0000
8     10 246933   rs1431845   G 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   A 0.220248000 1103  0.248 0.1599 0.1611
9     10 246955 rs556577288   C 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   T 0.000998403    5  0.000 0.0000 0.0000
10    10 246970 rs575589407   A 5008 synonymous_variant ZMYND11 NM_006624.5 protein_coding   G 0.000199681    1  0.000 0.0014 0.0000
   EUR_AF SAS_AF
1  0.0000 0.0000
2  0.0000 0.0000
3  0.0000 0.0000
4  0.0089 0.0143
5  0.0000 0.0000
6  0.0000 0.0000
7  0.0089 0.0010
8  0.2495 0.2843
9  0.0000 0.0051
10 0.0000 0.0000
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks.